# Why can I use mysql even when entering a wrong password when using sudo?

Tags: mysql

If I try to login to mysql with `mysql -u root -p` and enter the wrong password, then I get "access denied".

However, if I use `sudo mysql -u root -p` and enter the wrong mysql password, then I get access.

**Version**: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely due to the the root user using the `unix_socket` method of authentication. With this method a password it not used, only the operating system user matching the database user can login. So only the `root` OS user can login as the `root` database user. And although it's accepting a password on the command line it's being ignored.

See the [MariaDB knowledgebase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) for more detailed info including (if you really want/need) how to change to password authentication.

If you do `use mysql;` followed by `select user, plugin from user;` you can see which authentication plugins are configured for which users.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. I got the same behavior but when listing plugins it says `auth_socket` instead of `unix_socket` - I suppose they are the same thing.

Comment: @pgr yes, I think it's `auth_socket` in MySQL but `unix_socket` in MariaDB (a fork of MySQL).